# Connecting to redis on render.com

Tags: node.js, error-handling, redis, connection, render.com

I received this error when I wanted to connect to redis instance created on render.com. It should be mentioned that I enabled the instance to connect servers outside render.com.

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 6379
}

this is my redis config

```
import redis from "redis";
const client = redis.createClient({
  url: process.env.REDIS_URL_EXTERNAL,
});

export default client;
```

and this is how I connected the client in the server.js file

```
(async () => {
  await client.connect();
})();
```

I tried to connect to a Redis instance created on Render.com using the redis library in Node.js. I expected the connection to be successful, and for the Connected to Redis message to be logged to the console. However, I received the mentioned error.

Comment: Is the value of process.env.REDIS_URL_EXTERNAL correct when the code runs?

Comment: Came here to ask that same question. Redis is connecting to the default host and port. The environment variable not being set would cause this behavior.

Comment: I added dotenv.config() to the top of the file containing the config set up for redis, and it worked. Just mentioning dotenv.config() in the server.js file was not enough.